# Equal heights in a row? jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
$( window ).ready(function() {
            if ($( document ).width() > 576) {
                $('.col').each(function() {
                    var parentHeight = $(this).parent().height(); 
                    $(this).height(parentHeight);
                }); 
            }
            else {console.log("Mobile.")}
        });
```

This is my code.
I have html like this:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col col-8"><img src="assets/images/vizhanyo-erdeklodes.jpg" alt="Egy mém, ami neked nem tölt be." class="col-img"></div>
            <div class="col col-8"><img src="assets/images/mor-pluszmunka.jpg" alt="Egy mém, ami neked nem tölt be." class="col-img"></div>
            <div class="col col-8"><img src="assets/images/fizika-peldatar.jpg" alt="Egy mém, ami neked nem tölt be." class="col-img"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-8"><img src="assets/images/vizhanyo-szep-almokat.jpg" alt="Egy mém, ami neked nem tölt be." class="col-img"></div>
            <div class="col col-8"><img src="assets/images/vizhanyo-art.jpg" alt="Egy mém, ami neked nem tölt be." class="col-img"></div>
            <div class="col col-8"><img src="assets/images/mor-az-on-otthonaban.jpg" alt="Egy mém, ami neked nem tölt be." class="col-img"></div>
        </div>
```

The problem is that, the col's inside of a rows are not always perfect. Sometimes all the rows (except the first one) becomes ~5px high. Why?
You can check this bug out at [www.imarkus.me/2020b](http://imarkus.me/2020b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because the `row` height is defined by the image inside, which may have not been loaded at the point when your JS kicks in.

There are different solutions to that. The easist one would be to use https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height

You could also use flexbox: https://osvaldas.info/flexbox-based-responsive-equal-height-blocks-with-javascript-fallback
No JS required, but not all browsers support this feature.

If you want to stick with your solution: add a `resize` listener on your divs and on every resize adjust the height. Something like

```
var setHeight = function() {
    $('.col').each(function() {
        var parentHeight = $(this).parent().height(); 
        $(this).height(parentHeight);
    });
}
setHeight(); // initial call                
$('.row, .col').on('resize', setHeight);
```

(Untested)

**Edit** added `col` to the listener.

Comment: The flexblow doesn't work, it streches the image.

Your js is not working, same problem.

Comment: Flex-box-, not blow, should work. Guess you're using it the wrong way. Edited the js code, try this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add height and width to your images. If you add it your style sheet . It will keep images of fixed size every times.

```
img{
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px  
}
```

if you want different size of image on different size of screen. You can achive that by using @media tag.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 580px) {
   img{
       width: 20px;
       height: 20px  
   }
}
```

Now your height and width of images will be 20px.

Comment: The images has different sizes.

Comment: The size of rows are different because size of images are different. As column and rows are set to height:auto; it makes the row height of same as the highest  image. If you change your background color you can see it easily. To make all columns of  same height. you have to define height of images or use images which have same height.

Comment: Problem on resizing is image get stretched or shrink depending on its dimensions. To avoid it use images of same resolution. small images will be stretched  on resizing. One way is that you can crop your images to same size in some tool like (Photoshop,paint) before using them.

Answer (score 0):

I have to use a setTimeout before the function.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                if ($( document ).width() > 576) {
                $('.col').each(function() {
                    var parentHeight = $(this).parent().height(); 
                    $(this).height(parentHeight);
                }); 
            }}, 400)
        });
        $(window).resize(function(){location.reload();});
```

And on the last row I make the window reload if I resize the windows to run the function.

Comment: In case your image takes longer than 400 ms to load you'll get the same problem. And reloading a page on resize is a VERY bad idea.